# Linux Sed adding new lines during substitution

Tags: linux, replace, sed, newline, substitution

I've got a long CSV file, I'm trying to add a double quote to the end of each line so that all values are wrapped in "

If my file looks like this:

```
"value", "value2", "value3
"value", "value2", "value3
"value", "value2", "value3
```

I'm using this command:

```
sed -i 's/$/"/g' file.sql
```

and afterwards the file looks like this:

```
"value", "value2", "value3
"
"value", "value2", "value3
"
"value", "value2", "value3
"
```

Where is that new line coming from and how do I stop it from happening?

Comment: I don't get this result (GNU sed 4.2.1), which version are you using?

Comment: 4.2.1!!!I've worked it out, dos2unix, my newline characters are all broken as it's a CSV exported from Excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a fool. The CSV I'm using to build this SQL file has come from Excel.

I need to run `dos2unix` to fix the new line commands. Then it is working perfectly.

Thanks to Thor for verifying the command itself is fine.